# How can I fix not working cogs in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to create cogs but they don't work as they should. I don't really know what to do.
And when turning on the bot, there is no log message about loading the ping cog.

When typing the command:

```
ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not found
```

main.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from webserver import keep_alive
import os

intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".",intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('bot online'))
    print ("Bot is currently online!")

async def load():
  for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        await client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
        print(f"Loaded Cog: {filename[:-3]}")
    else:
        print("Unable to load pycache folder.")

keep_alive()
token = os.environ.get("discord_bot_secret")
client.run(token)
```

cogs/ping.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Pong!')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(ping(client))
```

I tried delete async def load(): and await before client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
but it didn't work and I got an error:

```
main.py:18: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
  client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

And I don't know why but, after deleting it, there was a message log about loading the ping cog.

Comment: Don't change presence in `on_ready`, it can make Discord disconnect you. Just set your presence when you create the Bot instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discord.py 2.0 update, loading extensions and adding cogs are now asynchronous, meaning that the [load_extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension) and [add_cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=add_cog#discord.ext.commands.Bot.add_cog) methods are now returning a coroutine that you need to call them using the `await` statement (async function), and the `setup` function in your extension file also needs to be an async function. I highly recommend you load the cogs in the new method [setup_hook](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=setup_hook#discord.ext.commands.Bot.setup_hook), example:

**Somewhere in main.py**

```py
@client.event
async def setup_hook():
  for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        await client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
        print(f"Loaded Cog: {filename[:-3]}")
    else:
        print("Unable to load pycache folder.")
```

**Setup function in cogs/ping.py**

```py
async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(ping(client))
```

See [discord.py Extension and Cog Loading / Unloading is Now Asynchronous](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous)

Comment: Thanks for your help, now it works as it should! And I'll ask you, maybe you know why when I add message reactions to a main.py:

[[[ @client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'nice':
        await message.add_reaction('') ]]]

all commands stop working and no log appears in the console?

Comment: `setup_hook` is not an event, you should just override the method in your own Bot subclass.

Comment: @xMerrvin it's in the FAQ... https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Comment: @stijndcl I already know that it isn't an event, but I used the event decorator because it's pretty much the same thing as subclassing the bot and setting attributes because that's what the deco does, and it's more understandable and also requires less space than subclassing, IMO. You may want to look at its [source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/client.py#L1226-L1255). But in the end, you do you.

Comment: @Catgal it doesn't really matter what the decorator does under the hood. Decorating something that isn't an event as "event" is very misleading & arguably makes it less understandable. Subclassing is 1 line, all you need for a very basic subclass is `class YourBotClass(commands.Bot):`, which is the same amount of lines as your decorator. If you don't want to do anything more then you don't have to & you can just use it like a regular `Bot` instance. If you're overriding a method, subclassing is always the cleanest & most readable way.